# MS SQL Server how to changing database name in same query?

Tags: sql-server

I have two different databases in the remote location, which i use through a linked server, every time when i do search i need to look both of them by passing a id. so i am using following two queries. but i want to user only one by passing the db name as a variable.

```
select * from [LINKED_SERVER].db2_WorkDB.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with(nolock) where id = 12
select * from [LINKED_SERVER].db3_SalesDB.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with(nolock) where id = 12
```

Is there any why by which i can pass a variable for db name that will allow me to write a single query and can use both db one by one.

NOTE:  i don't want to use a query as a string and them pass it to the EXEC.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `exec`, but that's far from nice...

```
DECLARE @tblName NVARCHAR(20)
SET @tblName = 'db2_WorkDB'

exec('SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER].' + @tblName + '.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with (nolock) where id = 12')
```

What would I do? I'd use a union:

```
select 'db2_WorkDB' as source, * from [LINKED_SERVER].db2_WorkDB.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with(nolock) where id = 12
union
select 'db3_SalesDB' as source, * from [LINKED_SERVER].db3_SalesDB.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with(nolock) where id = 12
```

If you want to include duplicate records, use `union all`.

Comment: About your Examples,

Example 1: my query is too big there is so many other variables, can't convert the whole query as a string and then pass it to the exec,

Example 2: here you are still using the same query 2 times just a database name is change.

Comment: Well - effectively you have to do the same. You're just calling the same query twice with different parameters. What's the difference?

Comment: in the question i provided tow queries to explain that i want to user a single query just need to change the db name

Comment: And you got an answer. Either you use `exec` or leave things as is. The question is (and you did not answer that): What *advantage* do you expect from calling *one* query *two times* instead of right away using a `union` query?

Comment: okay let me explain lets say my query have about 20 columns and each column is getting generated through a very complex sub query. but remember i have 2 different db that have a same table name, so if i use union then i have to duplicate all those 20 columns in the both query. that's mean every time i need to do some modification in the query i need to track on the both sides, this is what i don't want to do.

Comment: Then you *have* to use `exec`. There's no way to otherwise parameterize the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL

```
declare @dbname SYSNAME, @query as NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @dbname = 'your db name';
SET @query = 'SELECT FROM [YOUR SERVER].' + @dbname + '.dbo.Tbl_Jobseeke with(nolock) where id = 12';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```